# How to apply dplyr filter to list of data frames?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr

I have a `list()` of dataframes. I want to apply `dplyr`'s `filter()` to all of them.

Example code of what I have tried so far...

```
require(dplyr)
list.DFs <- list(df1,df2)
lapply(
  X = list.DFS,
  FUN = filter(Gold.fish.count=="Total")
)
```

But this gives an error: `Object 'Gold.fish.count' not found`.

Comment: Could also try SE for this, something like `lapply(list.DFS, dplyr::filter_, "Gold.fish.count=='Total'")` or just do the whole thing in base R `lapply(list.DFS, subset, Gold.fish.count=='Total')`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Using `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map(list.DFs, ~filter(.x, Gold.fish.count == "Total"))
```

Obviously, you can do exactly the same with lapply:

```
lapply(list.DFs, function(x) filter(x, Gold.fish.count == "Total"))
```

Comment: Both this answer and David Arenburg's show me in the console the filtered datasets. But in neither case is the filtered data frame saved to a variable. But this does answer the question as asked.

Comment: to save to a variable, just place `variable <-` at the beginning of the line

Comment: I meant saving each changed dataframe to the variable in which it is stored.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you want the filtered dataframes to be stored in a list assigned to the same variable, just overwrite the original list variable.

Comment: I've added a response which might address the point in the first comment above.  It adds the second part which I think @Username is looking for: to drop the data frames from the list where the condition is not met.

Answer (score 1):

Without having example data it's hard to identify exactly what you're after (check out how to use dput function in future). But some variation of the following might help:

```
indices <- sapply(list.DFs, function(x) x$Gold.fish.count == "Total")
list.DFs[indices]
```

The first line creates a list of logicals (True/False) where your condition is met. These logicals are then used to subset your original list of data frames.

If *Gold.fish.count* is a column that contains "*Total*" for every row then you can use an indexing variation:

```
indices <- sapply(list.DFs, function(x) x$Gold.fish.count[1] == "Total")
list.DFs[indices]
```

(Notice the additional *[1]*.)